# Swift convenience initialiser of ZeroMQ message crashes compiler

Tags: swift3, zeromq

I'm using Swift 3 and ZeroMQ in a Docker container and I'd like to add a couple of convenience initialisers to ZeroMQ.Message via an extension. What I currently have is crashing the compiler:

```
import Foundation
import ZeroMQ
import SwiftProtobuf

extension ZeroMQ.Message {
    convenience init?(string: String, encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) {
        var asData = string.data(using:encoding)!

        asData.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
            let unsafe = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: asData.count, alignedTo: 8)
            unsafe.copyBytes(from: bytes, count: asData.count)
            try? self.init(data: unsafe, size: asData.count)
        }
    }

    convenience init?(protobuf: SwiftProtobuf.Message) {
        guard let data = try? protobuf.serializedData() else {
            return nil
        }

        data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
            let unsafe = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: data.count, alignedTo: 8)
            unsafe.copyBytes(from: bytes, count: data.count)
            try? self.init(data: unsafe, size: data.count)
        }
    }
}
```

I realise there is a very high chance that I'm doing something wrong as this is very much a case of "in at the deep-end".

The compiler error is (with some manual line-wrapping in the interests of readability):

```
Compile Swift Module 'src' (3 sources)
swift: /home/buildnode/disk2/workspace/oss-swift-3.1-package-linux-ubuntu-16_04/swift/
   ... lib/SILGen/ManagedValue.h:202:
   ... swift::SILValue swift::Lowering::ManagedValue::getLValueAddress() const:
Assertion `isLValue() && "This isn't an lvalue"' failed.

0  swift           0x000000000362f718
1  swift           0x000000000362fe56
2  libpthread.so.0 0x00007fd55e321390
3  libc.so.6       0x00007fd55cc87428 gsignal + 56
4  libc.so.6       0x00007fd55cc8902a abort + 362
5  libc.so.6       0x00007fd55cc7fbd7
6  libc.so.6       0x00007fd55cc7fc82
7  swift           0x0000000000b5fbfc
8  swift           0x0000000000b55ccc
9  swift           0x0000000000b9c0bd
10 swift           0x0000000000b9be2e
11 swift           0x0000000000b6af32
12 swift           0x0000000000b1f8f2
13 swift           0x0000000000b61607
14 swift           0x0000000000b572ab
15 swift           0x0000000000b5579c
16 swift           0x0000000000b5d73a
17 swift           0x0000000000b5921a
18 swift           0x0000000000b51c94
19 swift           0x0000000000bc95eb
20 swift           0x0000000000bc4cb1
21 swift           0x0000000000bc4018
22 swift           0x0000000000baea2d
23 swift           0x0000000000bacefd
24 swift           0x0000000000b57284
25 swift           0x0000000000b55ccc
26 swift           0x0000000000b9c0bd
27 swift           0x0000000000b9be2e
28 swift           0x0000000000b3720f
29 swift           0x0000000000b26dba
30 swift           0x0000000000b1f099
31 swift           0x0000000000ba28d8
32 swift           0x0000000000ba180b
33 swift           0x0000000000ba17ce
34 swift           0x0000000000b23dcb
35 swift           0x0000000000b24dbb
36 swift           0x0000000000b25415
37 swift           0x000000000047f43d
38 swift           0x000000000043b277
39 libc.so.6       0x00007fd55cc72830 __libc_start_main + 240
40 swift           0x00000000004386b9
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /usr/bin/swift -frontend ...
1.  While silgen constructor initializer SIL function @_TFE3srcC6ZeroMQ7MessagecfT6stringSS8encodingVE10FoundationSS8Encoding_GSqS1__
    for 'init' at /app/Simple/Sources/extensions.swift:24:17
2.  While silgen closureexpr SIL function @_TFFE3srcC6ZeroMQ7MessagecFT6stringSS8encodingVE10FoundationSS8Encoding_GSqS1__U_FGSPVs5UInt8_T_
    for expression at [/app/Simple/Sources/extensions.swift:27:33 - line:31:9]
    RangeText="{ (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
            let unsafe = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: asData.count, alignedTo: 8)
            unsafe.copyBytes(from: bytes, count: asData!.count)
            try? self.init(data: unsafe, size: asData!.count)
        }"
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Aborted
```

Similar code but following the factory method pattern is fine, so I believe the problem to be in the usage of `try?` and the call to the designated initialiser.

**Edit:**
An alternative approach to pull the `self.init(...)` out of the trailing closure:

```
convenience init?(string: String, encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) {
    guard let data = string.data(using:encoding) else {
        return nil
    }

    let unsafe = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: data.count, alignedTo: 8)

    data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
        unsafe.copyBytes(from: bytes, count: data.count)
    }
    do {
        try self.init(data: unsafe, size: data.count)
    } catch {
        unsafe.deallocate(bytes: data.count, alignedTo: 8)
    }
}
```

The above yields an error that I don't understand:

```
extensions.swift:41:17: error: 'self' used inside 'catch' block reachable from self.init call
    convenience init?(string: String, encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) {
```

Replacing the `do { ... } catch { ... }` with a one-liner satisfies the compiler, but leaks the buffer in the case that the initialiser throws (ZeroMQ takes ownership of the memory in the successful case):

```
try? self.init(data: unsafe, size: data.count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my lack of familiarity with the ZeroMQ API meant I was going down the wrong path and over-complicating things unnecessarily. ZeroMQ already has a method that encapsulates the `unsafeMutableBytes` aspects:

```
public func send(_ data: Data, mode: SendMode = []) throws -> Bool
```

... so all I needed to do to achieve my goal of increasing the convenience of sending Protobufs was to add the trivial extension method to ZeroMQ's `Socket`:

```
extension Socket {
    func send(_ proto: SwiftProtobuf.Message, mode: SendMode = []) throws -> Bool {
        let data = try proto.serializedData()
        return try self.send(data, mode: mode)
    }
}
```